# Core Data app failed to launch in time

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, appdelegate

I have an app that creates a persistent store in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Adding the store can apparently take too long, which causes iOS to terminate the app before it finishes launching. 
How to add the store to the coordinator off the main thread? Any examples?
[stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13334035/1857334)

OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.maksanzhi.person failed to launch in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 13.470 (user 13.470, system 0.000), 22% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.343, 1% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator

if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"COOLPERSONS.sqldata"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]]) {

    NSURL *defaultStoreURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"COOLPERSONS" withExtension:@"sqldata"];
    if (defaultStoreURL) {
        [fileManager copyItemAtURL:defaultStoreURL toURL:storeURL error:NULL];
        [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:storeURL];
    }
}


NSError *error = nil;
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return _persistentStoreCoordinator;



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
MainViewController *cvtc = (MainViewController *)[[nav viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
cvtc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
[self setAppereance];
return YES;
```

}

Comment: Just creating a store does not usually take much time.  Can you show us all of your startup code?  Perhaps the profiler will be of use to you in figuring out where your launch time is being eaten up.

Comment: I edited the question with more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as general advice you should not create nothing heavy in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method. The Core data Persistent Store isn't heavy to create, but in the feature could be, due to migration process. To be sure that is the persistent store and not something else, try to comment out that part of code.
Are you initializing the store with data?

Comment: Yes, i initialize the store with data. Can i send or share my code?

Comment: That is the point. You should not do that here. Better to show a modal view controller, with a spinner from the root view controller and initialize here. applicationDidFinishLaunching must return as soon as possible. I don't need you code, I'm pretty sure that the proble is here.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrea, i'm new iOS Dev Please how to show  a modal view controller with spinner?

Comment: Hello Astakhoff it would require different time for do that and I think is better for you to understand instead of just copy and paste. Core Data isn't a beginner topic, you should have a very solid ground on OSX programming or iOS programming I'm pretty sure that you will understand and find the way to do that. Essentially you are blocking the main thread with that operation, if appDidFinishLauching didn't return in a certain amount of time it will call the watchdog that kills your app. What you need to do is copy all the initialization data of the DB somewhere else. Cheers